# Ubuntu не видит мониторы и дублирует их

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amd, radeon, монитор

В настройках Ubuntu (с оболочкой Pantheon) не видит мои мониторы(2) у каждого 1366x768 вот скриншоты:

[image: Настройки]

xrandr:

[image: Xrandr]

Использую AMD Radeon HD 5670

Comment: Вопрос с мониторами еще не решен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хорошо что вы добавили вывод `xrandr`. Из того кусочка вывода понятно, что *не удалось получить размер гаммы для выходного значения по умолчанию.*
О чём это говорит?   По какой-то причине, нет возможности изменить разрешение экрана до максимально поддерживаемого разрешения вашего монитора. Такая ситуация возможна в линукс системе, при установке двух и более мониторов, причин может быть несколько.
По скрину видно, что вы пытаетесь сделать через графический интерфейс, но он вас ограничивает разрешением экрана в `800х600`.  Если вы захотите установить разрешение выше или ниже тех что есть, то у вас, к сожалению,  ничего не выйдет таким способом. Далее вернемся к `xrandr`. У данной утилиты немного больше возможностей, чем у графического интерфейса.
Чтобы посмотреть текущие параметры системы, запустите утилиту без параметров:

```
$ xrandr
```

Так как необходимого вам разрешения нет, вам необходимо его добавить вручную. Для этого сначала нужно конвертировать обычную запись в формат VESA. Используйте для этих целей утилиту `cvt`

```
$ sudo cvt 1366 768 60
```

Ваше разрешение экрана и частота должны совпадать на обоих экранах (т.е. доступны в их характеристиках). 
Копируем из вывода утилиты всё, что написано после `Modeline`. Далее используем скопированный текст в `xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1366x768_60.00" и далее весь вывод до конца
```

Дальше необходимо добавить созданное разрешение к списку доступных, для нужного нам экрана:

```
$ xrandr --addmode [ваш способ подключения, к примеру через: HDMI-1]  1366x768_60.00
```

Чтоб проверить способ подключения мониторов:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
```

Далее просто необходимо активировать:

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1366x768_60.00
```

Запускаем вновь `xrandr` и проверяем параметры.  Если все прошло успешно, то необходимо сохранить изменения настроек в конфигурационном файле `~/.xprofile`

```
$ nano ~/.xprofile
```

Для уточнения любой информации по системе есть хорошая утилита `inxi`, если отвутствует у вас на ПК, установить:

```
$ sudo apt install inxi
```

Например, нужна информация про установленные видеокарты:

```
$ inxi -G
```

Также собрать информацию можно таким способом:

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
```

*Ссылки:*

[xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default на Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=xrandr%3A+Failed+to+get+size+of+gamma+for+output+default)
[Xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output на Linux Mint Forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=202637)
[xrandr - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xrandr)
[manpages.ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/inxi.1.html)

Comment: xrandr полный...

Comment: Ну тогда просто `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1366x768`

Comment: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
warning: output HDMI-1 not found; ignoring

Comment: HDMI-1 DVI-0, но в xranr'e только default

Comment: видеокарта от amd и процессор тоже

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю проблему? Порты видит, но при запуске `xrandr --addmode DVI-0 1366x768_60.00` выдает ошибку?

Comment: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "DVI-0"

Comment: Есть одна в материнке

Comment: пытался, не видит

Comment: Дополнительные драйверы отсутствуют

Comment: Проприетарные драйверы остутствуют

Comment: На сайтах нету, слишком старая

Comment: @Inakoto Добавьте в ваш вопрос пожалуйста информацию о процессоре и видеокарте, а то сложно гадать

Comment: нашел - amd radeon hd 5670

Comment: попробую ставить драйвер с амд сайта

Comment: Собираюсь брать новую видеокарту, GeForce 1050

Comment: Беру Palit GeForce GTX 1050 STORMX [NE51050018FE-1070F]