# Как подключить второй монитор в ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia, hp

Подключение по hdmi -> dvi-i
На windows системе(этот же ноутбук) монитор сразу включается и отображает рабочий стол.
В ubuntu нет. Но если вставлять кабель hdmi то монитор загорается но пишет что нет сигнала.

Установлен драйвер nvidia последний.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
xrandr пишет :
HDMI-1-1 disconnected

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1920x1080     60.02 +  60.01*   59.97    59.96    59.93    40.02  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96  
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x267) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
xrandr --listmonitors  
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP-1-1 1920/382x1080/215+0+0  eDP-1-1
```

Comment: Отключить вторую видеокарту в BIOS (интегрированную, если она есть на борту), установить драйвера от Nvidia (но видно что стоят, судя по выводу), и перезагрузить ПК после этого

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/934399/262779

Comment: В Ubuntu, Mint, Debian, Manjaro и ещё нескольких, подключал второй монитор успешно с драйверами Nvidia. В Ubuntu был заглюк (правда только 1 раз), как раз-таки из-за 2 одновременно включеных GPU (тогда проблему решил отключив одну из них)

Comment: `xrandr пишет : HDMI-1-1 disconnected` -правильно, потому что его надо подключить. В ссылке что я добавил есть ответ

Comment: Добавил как в том вопросе. По прежнему не видит. В вопросе обновил что выводит xrandr.

Comment: xrandr --listmonitors 
выводит только 1 монитор. Как именно подключить дополнительные монитор и назначить ему HDMI-1-1?

Comment: там в ссылке всё было, вариант рабочий, я его ранее проверял. Ну если тот вариант сложный и с драйверами проблема, то тут как и в вышеупомянутом Windows - снести драйвера и установить заново новые. 418 драйвер не стабилен, так что если что могут быть сюрпризы, 390 последний стабильный, скоро должен обновиться в стандартных репозиториях.

Comment: Спасибо за выложенный вариант решения, костыльный он конечно, слишком костыльный, но если рабочий это хорошо. Я лично не гонюсь за изменением нумерации драйверов (и ядер в том числе), предпочитаю стабильность. Manjaro последняя  подтянула уже 410-й, думаю, что в этом году и Debian 9 подтянется. Ну Canonical больше экспериментировать любят, так что на Ubuntu все будет ещё быстрее обновляться

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/963436/262779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить драйверы с сайта nvidia.
Выбрать Linux и скачать драйверы с расширением run.
После скачивания файл .run нужно сделать исполняемым.  Но не запускать.

Далее важно чтобы версии уже установленных драйверов не совпадали с устанавливаемыми иначе будет конфликт в ядре. Например скачиваем 418.54 и установлен 418.54. Если так то через систему обновлений нужно установить какую нибудь другую версию драйвера.

Далее запуститься в режиме восстановления и зайти в Root режим. 
запустить скачанный файл и если спросит перезаписать существующие файлы. 
После этого нужно перезагрузиться. Далее сразу включаться оба монитора. И уже их можно настраивать как угодно. Они везде будут видны.