# Как установить драйвера на Nvidia GeForce 610M Debian 9?

Tags: linux, debian, драйвер, nvidia

APT ругается:

```
Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:

     libglx0 : Зависит: libglx-mesa0 но он не будет установлен
     xserver-xorg-input-all : Зависит: xserver-xorg-input-libinput но он не будет установлен
                              Рекомендует: xserver-xorg-input-wacom но он не будет установлен
     xserver-xorg-video-all : Зависит: xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu но он не будет установлен
                              Зависит: xserver-xorg-video-ati но он не будет установлен
                              Зависит: xserver-xorg-video-fbdev но он не будет установлен
                              Зависит: xserver-xorg-video-nouveau но он не будет установлен
                              Зависит: xserver-xorg-video-vesa но он не будет установлен
                              Зависит: xserver-xorg-video-vmware но он не будет установлен
                              Рекомендует: xserver-xorg-video-intel но он не будет установлен
                              Рекомендует: xserver-xorg-video-qxl но он не будет установлен
    E: Ошибка, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve сгенерировал повреждённые пакеты. Это может быть вызвано отложенными (held) пакетами.
    `
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91755/discussion-on-question-by-------nvidia-gefo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавить `non-free` репозиторий (если не добавлен).

Как администратор (через `sudo` или `root`), откройте `/etc/apt/sources.list` с помощью `nano` или `vim`(что удобнее) и добавьте `non-free` репозиторий.

Далее когда всё будет готово, обновите индексные файлы репозитория (показываю как от `root`, если используется `sudo` соответственно везде его добавлять к указанным командам):

```
# apt update
```

Установите утилиту `nvidia-detect`, выполнив следующую команду:

```
# apt -y install nvidia-detect
```

Определите модель своей карты Nvidia и предложите драйвер Nvidia. Для этого выполните указанную выше установленную команду nvidia-detect (в вашем случае так как вы знаете какая у вас модель точно, в этом особой необходимости нет):

```
# nvidia-detect
```

После введения команды, будет предложен подходящий драйвер.

Далее, установите рекомендуемый драйвер с предыдущего шага:

```
# apt install nvidia-driver
```

Все готово, перезагрузите ваш ПК и в работу.

```
# systemctl reboot
```

Добавляю источник, в нём же указанно как установить с оффсайта.

[Источник](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-on-debian-10-buster-linux)

Также драйвера можно установить через Synaptic. Если на ПК есть интегрированная видеокарта, лучше её отключить в BIOS и оставить только Nvidia. Стабильный драйвер 390-й, для Debian 9, на данный момент, но можно ставить и другой если необходимо.

Comment: Инструкция стандартная, я по ней ставил пару раз (проверенно)