# Как отключить дискретную видеокарту Nvidia?

Tags: linux, debian, bios, nvidia

Как отключить видеокарту Nvidia? В BIOS нет такой настройки.
Ноутбук шумит и греется, драйвера не встают нормально.

Comment: А как вы ее включили? У меня другой диструбиутив Linux и я ставил драйвера и предпринимал кучу шагов для включения. Если вы шли по похожему пути, то просто откатите как было. Ну и модель ноутбука тоже скажите

Comment: Я просто установил debian и у меня автоматически установился nouvea, и все начало работать

Comment: https://imgur.com/5PySfib вот характеристика ноута    
https://imgur.com/3tHTa80 вот характеристика ОС

Comment: и все де скажите модель ноутбука.  И добавьте вместе с картинками в вопрос)

Comment: Я себе накатывал bumbleebee и у меня сразу все заработала. Nvidia включалась только для игр.

Comment: nouveau - надо убирать и ставить от nvidia

Comment: @Viktorov, у вас может AMD? nvidia+nouveau - это постоянная головная боль

Comment: @PavelGridin у меня intel встроенная и nvidia дискретная. Головная боль тоже была сначала. Но bumbleebee меня спасло. Попытка установить драйвера от Nvidia тоже не прокатила. Так же работала только nvidia, что приводило к быстрой разрядке ноутбука

Answer (score 2):

*BIOS*

Так как вопрос именно по отключению дискретной видеокарты и было упомянуто что в BIOS якобы такой настройки нет, на него и отвечаю. В твоём BIOS, а насколько помню, в каком-то из комментариев под вопросами ты писал, что он у тебя [AMI BIOS](https://ami.com/en/) (сокращаю, до абревиатуры), необходимо сделать следующие шаги.

Зайдя в BIOS у тебя будет сине-серая меню, в верхней панели навигации должны находиться следующие пункты:

> `Main` | `Advanced` | `Power` | `Boot` | `Tools` | `Exit`

Сама меню вверху, в AMI разных годов может быть разная.
Далее зайди в:

> `Advanced` -> `Chipset` -> `SouthBridge Configuration`

Далее, нажимаешь на `Primary Graphics Adapter`, должно всплыть окошко с вариантами выбора карты. `IGP` - соответственно отвечает за интегрированную видеокарту, а `PCIE` за Nvidia в твоём случае. Выбираешь нужную для активации. Там с которой начинается, она будет соответственно в приоритете, после выбора.

Далее необходимо выйди до уровня общего меню и соответственно выбрать пункт

> `Exit` -> `Exit & Save Changes`

Ну, а дальше просто перезагрузка ноутбука с новой конфигурацией. Вроде бы ничего сложного.

---

*Необходимые системные данные для устранения проблемы:*

Что касается самой OS Debian 9, то вывести данные по поводу самого BIOS в терминале, можно воспользовавшись командой (показываю всё от root):

```
# dmidecode --type 0
```

Данные по поводу материнской платы:

```
# dmidecode --type baseboard
```

Чтобы собрать ещё больше информации, можно воспользоваться `lspci` - это стандартный инструмент для запроса устройств, подключенных к любой PCI-совместимой шине:

```
# lspci -nn
```

Таже можно сократить вывод до:

```
# lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
```

Если не установлен nvidia-detect, [можно его установить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/963441/262779) и собрать данные (хотя, данных с `lspci` должно хватить), введя в терминале:

```
# nvidia-detect
```

Используя вышеуказанные команды, можно собрать всю необходимую информацию, для дальнейшей работы над устранением проблемы.

---

*Nvidia*

Если возникла необходимость полного удаления драйверов от Nvidia, это довольно просто сделать. Выполни следующую команду, чтобы удалить все пакеты, которые начинаются с `nvidia` в имени пакета:

```
# apt purge nvidia-*
```

Comment: Добавь пожалуйста точную модель ноутбука, так проще будет разобраться с проблемой. Сама меню вверху в AMI разных годов может быть разная

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, да и модель ноутбука уже норм не найти так как наклейки стерты коробки нет(

Comment: Также очень много информации о ПК, можно собрать с помощью утилиты `inxi`

Comment: @L.F.C. Полезный, содержательный ответ (+)