# Установка драйверов Nvidia на Debian в Google Cloud

Tags: linux, debian, драйвер, nvidia, google-cloud

Проблема с загрузкой драйверов на Nvidia P100 в виртуальную машину Google Cloud'а. Перекопал достаточное количество форумов, но не нашел решения проблемы. Поделитесь гайдиком. И еще вопрос, почему видеокарта отображается в 3D контроллере?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эм, а почему она там *не* должна отображаться?

Comment: Т.е. так и должно быть? А есть рекомендации или инструкции по установке драйвера?

Comment: Из моего опыта, на реальную машину при установке Debian в начале лучше установить microcode, перезагрузить, а потом ставить дрова от Nvidia или AMD. На реальную и виртуальную ставил, но вот с облаком не пришлось как-то, небыло такой необходимости

Comment: Cпасибо, L.F.C, а не посоветуете какой-нибудь гайд или мануал? А как мне поможет microcode?  Еще у меня была ситуация, когда на реальной машине, тоже на Debian,  команда lspci ничего не выводила, буквально останавливалась, не позволяя завершить ее, помогало лишь закрытие терминала, но сам процесс не завешался. Не подскажите, с чем связано?

Comment: там microcode необходимо выбирать исходя из процессора (Intel/AMD), внимательно с этим, все есть в официальных доках на сайте [Debian](https://www.debian.org/)

Comment: amd64-microcode или intel-microcode - чтоб уменьшить круг поиска

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/963441/262779

Comment: Большое спасибо, пойду пробовать)

Comment: *а не посоветуете какой-нибудь гайд или мануал?* - https://youtu.be/BWBHJmAmZgk и офсайт дистрибутива

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5RJzZxQ62U

Comment: Спасибо! У меня получилось. Вы мне очень помогли!