# Ubuntu на ноутбуке не видит второй монитор

Tags: ubuntu

Ноутбук xiaomi gaming laptop 2019 rtx 2060.
В ноуте две видюхи, интел и энвидэ. 
Второй монитор, вставленный в hdmi никак не определяется(
Только вчера поставил ubuntu

Comment: попробуйте использовать другие драйвера. откройте в параметрах репозиториев вкладку дополнительные драйверы. попробуйте использовать проприоритарные драйвера или любые другие из списка.

Comment: @JamesM Добрый день. Когда выбираю проприетарные драйвера, монитор вообще перестает определяться

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/931228/262779